# undefine method submit_to_remote

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ajax-on-rails

```
<%= submit_to_remote(:category, :url => params[:id].blank? ? {:action => 'create'} : {:action => "update", :id => @category}) do %>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><%= text_field(:category, :name, :size => 20) %></td>
            <td><%= submit_tag(params[:id].blank? ? "New": "Edit") %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<% end %>
```

I want to create new record using Ajax. I got **error undefined method submit_to_remote** I declared prototype file in layout. 
                  waiting for ans.......

Comment: You've asked 12 questions, but you haven't given any of the answers a single up-vote, or marked any answers as correct. People will be more likely to help you if you show a little appreciation for their efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it looks like your `submit_to_remote` is trying to define a `form` - so use `form_for` or `form_tag`.

Secondly `submit_to_remote` no longer exists in Rails 3. You need the `:remote => true` option of `form_tag`, which will let UJS (Unobtrusive JavaScript) step in and make the AJAX happen.

See [some docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag).

Comment: is any more other changes needed?

Comment: Hard to say without a fair bit more code. But assuming this is a form for a `Category` model, and you have an `@category` in hand (either new or existing), then it looks like a all right start.